# Find function works weird

Tags: excel, excel-formula, find

Well... It's really weird, but let me explain.

I am trying to get the country string from the A1. So i should get the position of second  # and after that i can use MID and get the country. But, well.. Please check out.

Here is the situation:

A1: "Abergwili# Wales# United Kingdom"
B1: =FIND("#";A1;1) > Result: 10  >> Correct!
C1: =FIND("#";A1;B1) > Result: 10  >> What??? It should output 7! I really don't get it!

Any help?

Comment: Last argument in find() is the start number, not another cell to test.

Comment: Use: `=FIND("#";A1;B1+1)`, Otherwise you start from the same position an hashtag was found previously, hence it was returning the exact same output. Though not `7`, it will output `17`. That being said, what exactly is your goal here. There may be better ways to pull the strings.

Answer (score 0):

The `FIND` function in Excel uses the last argument as the string index to start searching from.  If that index matches the target string, it will return that index again.  There are a few options:

- You could restructure your current `FIND` function to start at the character *after* `B1`'s result, which will produce the formula `=FIND("#",A1,B1+1)`.  To get the position relative to `B1`, you could subtract the value of `B1`, which creates `=FIND("#",A1,B1+1)-B1`. (This is similar to JvdV's answer)
- You could explicitly search through the remaining substring after the first match using the `RIGHT` function, which transforms the original function to `=FIND("#",RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-B1))`, which automatically returns the result relative to the last match.  To get the absolute result, you could add the value of `B1` back in, creating `=FIND("#",RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-B1))+B1`.

Good luck!

(Side note - You probably want commas instead of semicolons, unless your Excel is set up to work with them.  My Excel complained mightily when testing with ; characters)